# how to add an action on UITextView return/search key?(swift 2)

Tags: xcode, swift, keyboard, return, uitextview

I have a UITextView which I am using as text entry in a translation application. When the user presses return/search then I want to do some action e.g. searching for word from textView. I want to do some action like we do with IBAction.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Set up delegate of the `textView`.  Than add `shouldChangeTextInRange`  for detecting of the return/search buttons and `performAction` for you're custom action.

```
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        self.textView.delegate = self
    }

    func textView(textView: UITextView, shouldChangeTextInRange  range: NSRange, replacementText text: String) -> Bool {
      if (text == "\n") {
         textView.resignFirstResponder()
         performAction()
      }
      return true
    }

    func performAction() {

    }
```

Comment: This is the same for UITextView i will edit it for you